# Finding the eccentricity and the semi-major axis

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

**Statement:** The equation of a conic with a focus at the origin $Ax+By+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=c^2$ satisfies $A^2+B^2=1+2hc^2$. Show that the eccentricity and the semi-major axis of the conic are $\varepsilon=\sqrt{1+2hc^2}$ and $a=-1/(2h)$ (for $h\neq0$).

**Approach:** First of all, for me it's strange that a conic is given by a non-quadratic expression. So what I did was to square both sides of equation $Ax+By+-c^2=-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and apply a general formula to find the eccentricity in terms of the conic coefficients. Although I found the correct answer for $\varepsilon$, the calculations were tedious and I have the intuition that there is a simpler way to deduce it. In the case of the semi-major axis $a$, I haven't found a way to compute it. So in conclusion, I would aprecciate that someone helps me in understanding how to deduce this two quantities (and maybe give me some intrinsics of the geometry behind).

Thank you very much!

PD: This problem comes from an approach to solve the 2-body problem of celestial mechanics if anyone is curious.

Comment: For the first part; in the form $x^2+y^2=(A^2+B^2)(\frac{c^2}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}-\frac{Ax+By}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}})^2,$ we see the directrix $\frac{c^2}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}=\frac{Ax+By}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$ and corresponding focus $(0,0)$ and eccentricity $\varepsilon^2=A^2+B^2.$

Comment: Problem  would 've been bit better if $\sqrt{A^2+B^2}=1-2hc^2$ given  for a positive major axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substituting polar coordinates $x = \rho \cos \theta$ and $y = \rho \sin ⁡\theta$ yields the equation
\begin{equation}
A \rho \cos \theta + B \rho \sin \theta + \rho = c^2
\end{equation}
The major axis is attained at $\theta_0$ and $\theta_0 + \pi$ for which $\rho'(\theta_0)=0$, since these yield the maximum and minimum radii. Implicit differentiation of the above equation and substitution of $\rho'(\theta_0)=0$ yields
\begin{equation}
-A\sin⁡\theta_0+B\cos\theta_0=0
\end{equation}
hence $\tan⁡\theta_0=B/A$. Substitute into the original equation and solve for $\rho(\theta_0)$ to obtain
\begin{equation}
\rho(\theta_0)=\frac{c^2}{1-\sqrt{1+2hc^2}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\rho(\theta_0+\pi)=\frac{c^2}{1+\sqrt{1+2hc^2}}
\end{equation}
The major axis is therefore
\begin{equation}
2a = \rho(\theta_0)+\rho(\theta_0+\pi)=-\frac{1}{h}
\end{equation}
On the other hand, the distance between the two foci is
\begin{equation}
2d = \rho(\theta_0)-\rho(\theta_0+\pi)=-\frac{\sqrt{1+2hc^2}}{h}
\end{equation}
so the eccentricity is the ratio
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon=\frac{2d}{2a}=\sqrt{1-2hc^2}
\end{equation}
[image]

Comment: Nice ellipse,how is it drawn with the symbols?

Comment: It's just a screenshot of a GeoGebra construction. :-)

Comment: Labels/ greek  symbols like $\rho(\theta+\pi)$ can be written into the drawing?

Comment: Yes, you can enter text using simple LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks, that may help me.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$\tan \alpha= \frac{B}{A},\, \sin \alpha=\frac {B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}},\,\cos \alpha=\frac {A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}},\, x=r \cos \theta,  y=r \sin \theta,$$

in an attempt to cast the given equation into the classical Newtonian conic form.

We have $$ \frac {Ax}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} + \frac {By}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} + \frac{r}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} =\frac{c^2}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} $$

$$  r \cos \alpha \cos \theta + r \sin \alpha \sin \theta +\frac{r}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} =\frac{c^2}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} $$

Divide by $r$ and rearrange

$$ \frac{1+ \sqrt{{A^2+B^2}} \cos{(\theta+\alpha)}} {c^2} = \frac{1}{r}$$

compare with Newtonian Conic form

$$\frac {1+\varepsilon \cos \theta_{rot}}{p}=\frac {1}{r}$$

$$ \sqrt{A^2+B^2}= \sqrt {1+2 h c^2} = \varepsilon $$

Latus Rectum

$$p= \frac {b^2}{a}=c^2 =a (1-\varepsilon^2) \rightarrow a=-\frac{1}{2h}. $$